# How do I reference the last row in a named Excel table?

Tags: excel

I am currently trying to format one column of my table so that if there are any names that match in another column, the cell in the original column will be highlighted. Here's an example of what I mean:

[image: Example data set]

Row 10 has a prerequisite of the M6A1. However, row 11 has a name of M6A1. I would like the M6A1 in row 10 to be highlighted.

To do this, I figured I would use COUNTIF, with the range from the current row (10 in this case) down to the bottom row (14). I don't want to hard-code in 14 however, as the list length will change. Therefore, I thought that I could just call the last row in the table, but that's not a feature apparently. I would like to know either how to dynamically reference the last row in this table, or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Not sure if this will work and I do not have the ability to test it out now but you might be able to do a conditional formatting rule based on a vlookup.

Comment: I would use vlookup, but the table is going to be sorted by BR and not name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you consider using built-in Excel functions you can get the last row of the table or named range this way:

- `=ROW(NAMED_RANGE or TABLE_NAME)-1+ROWS(NAMED_RANGE or TABLE_NAME)` - for the last row of the table;
- `=ROW(NAMED_RANGE or TABLE_NAME)-1+COUNT(NAMED_RANGE or TABLE_NAME)` - for the last record in the table.

Comment: I ended up having to use a hidden column to make it work, but I got what I wanted. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

For the last Row

```
=MAX(ROW(TABLE_NAME))
```

Comment: `=INDEX(Table[Attribute],MAX(ROW(Table))-1)`

Answer (score 1):

To get the last row of your table, use `Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row`, provided your "A" column does not have any blank cells. If it does, a better way to do it is to use `Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row`.
The `.End(Direction)` method goes to the last cell before a blank a cell in a  given direction (Up, Down, Left or Right, preceded by xl), starting from the specified Range, and the `.Row` method gets the row number of a given Range/Cell.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this code:

```
lastRow = ws.Range(affectedTable).Row + ws.Range(affectedTable).Rows.Count - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on a previous answer with what worked for me. Below is another solution that does not require VBA but will return the last populated row instead of the last row of the table area.

COUNT(TABLE_NAME) will return the total number of filled cells in the table. If there are blank cells, this may not work correctly.

Since we are trying to count rows, it makes more sense to use only one column of the table which will always be filled (in many cases the first column). Using the built-in COUNTA function, we can count only the cells that have a value. Use structured references to specify a single column in the table or named range:

```
=ROW(TABLE_NAME)-1+COUNTA(TABLE_NAME[COLUMN_NAME])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that inside the table (totals cell for example), just use offset (no empty rows of course):
[code]=OFFSET(tblName[[#Totals],[ColName]],-1,0)[/code]

If it is out of table, there are many good solutions.