# Excel - how to achieve the equivalent result of using "Ctrl+End" by using Functions

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, row

I have a table in a single sheet excel where the fields are date and consecutive Columbus to enter numbers for currency of different denominations and a total column at the end.

The table gets appended by a row every day.

I want to multiply the column headers (denominations e.g. 2000, 500, 200 etc.) with the denomination number for the latest day. Means the header row × the last row of the table.

I can't achieve this using last blank row, since I have different other data below the Table.

I'm also looking for a solution that doesn't involve VBA.

So, can anyone please help me.

Comment: Do you also include the date in the last row?

Comment: Is the Table you're mentioning an actual Table? The you could refer to it's last row using INDEX and table references MAX ROW, or LARGE ROW.

Comment: No. Actually the requirement is to find out the total amount of money corresponding to a particular denomination. Also I'll be showing the increase/decrease to it.

Comment: I'm very thankful to Naresh for doing so much hard-work to explain in detail all the different methods to approach this problem. I apologize for not providing the data with the question. I'll try to find out the best suitable method for my problem.

Comment: @Naresh - I am not yet eligible for upvoting your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Method: Without Table (Control+T) Range**
Formula in B1 is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:D2,INDEX(B3:D19,MATCH(LOOKUP(1,1/(A2:A19<>""),A2:A19),A3:A19,0),))
```

[image]

There are 3 methods to get the last row/value

First - Cell F1 formula `=MATCH(9.9999E+307,Sheet2!A1:A19)` returns last nonblank cell index in the given column range.

Second - Cell F2 Formula
`=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A19<>""),A1:A19)` gives last nonblank cell value in the given column range

Third - Cell F3 Formula which is useful in this case as there is data below the referred table.
`=LOOKUP(1,1/(A1:A19<>""),A1:A19)` returns the nonblank cell value before the first blank cell

**Second Method: With Table (Control+T) Range**
Formula in B1 is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VALUE(Table1[[#Headers],[2000]:[200]]),INDEX(Table1[[2000]:[200]],MATCH(MAX(Table1[Date]),Table1[Date],0),))
```

In this method, the table range get automatically updated in when a new record is added to the table.

[image]

So in both the above cases, if a record is added below (adjacent to) the last used cell, the sumproduct formula will refer to that record.

Comment: Also, for [named excel ranges refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48673784/9808063)

Answer (score 1):

What I actually ended up using is the Concatenation function to refer to the last row of the Table, wich I got by using TableName inside the ROW & ROWS functions.

1. TableName[[#Headers],[2000]]*INDIRECT("C"&ROW(TableName)-1+ROWS(TableName))
2. TableName[[#Headers],[500]]*INDIRECT("C"&ROW(TableName)-1+ROWS(TableName))
   and so on.

This did not have any issues with all the data I have below my Table.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Glad to learn .. Also, if the question is answered with this, you can accept your own answer with a click on the tick mark on the left of the answer.