# Excel conditional table data validation for last row or some current row column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I cannot make a conditional drop down menu in an Excel table. I think it's possible but I get an error that I don't (yet) understand.
Say I want that the very last row in a table (that some users will edit) only shows a sublist of a larger table (In my example, only coming events although I want the rest of the column to remain valid with any value from the larger table).

[image]

Getting the last row is not the source of the issue (cf. [How do I reference the last row in a named Excel table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48673163/how-do-i-reference-the-last-row-in-a-named-excel-table) for instance), but the formula I add in `Data > Data validation > List` is wrong:

```
IF ( test last row = TRUE, INDIRECT("table_coming_events["coming events]"), INDIRECT("table_events[events]") )
```

or for the sake of this example:

```
IF( [@user] = "Alice", INDIRECT("table_events[events]"),  INDIRECT("table_coming_events[coming events]" ) )
```

### Update

Thanks to Jos Woolley's comment, I understand that Structured References (like [@user]) are not allowed in Data Validation. For getting the last row number, I wanted to use `IF( ROW() = ROW(table_subscription[#Headers]) + ROWS(table_subscription)` but this won't be allowed neither. So I put the last row number of table subscription into another table:

[image]

What's the error in my updated formula?

```
=IF( ROW() = INDIRECT("lastline[lastline]"), INDIRECT("table_coming_events[coming events]"), INDIRECT("table_events[events]") )
```

I now get a pop up telling me *the source is recognized as erroneous*. Which source? is it `ROW()`? How to correct this formula?

NB. I have a French edition; hence, my formulas are translated. I hope not introducing a misleading translation error.

### Follow up

I came up with this solution:

- I created a *number* column populated with this formula:

```
= ROW() - ROW(table_subscription[#Headers])
```

- then I calculated the number of rows into a cell (not a table) called **number_items**

```
=ROWS(table_subscription)
```

- I also gave a name to events (`all_events` referencing `table_events[events]`)
  and to coming events (`coming_events` referencing `table_coming_events[coming events]`).
- I did the validation as a List with this formula:

```
=IF(C3 = number_items; coming_events; all_events)
```

I am annoyed to use `C3` in Data validation formula and not any kind of structured reference or name, but at least, it works!

[image]

Comment: Your second formula won't work, since you can't use Structured References within a Data Validation formula. Your first appears to be missing a closing parenthesis for the first `INDIRECT`. Otherwise, perhaps share your definition for `test last row`?

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten, if I ever knew, that _Structured References_ were not allowed in Data Validation context.

Comment: Could you move the solution here into a self-answer? We like maintaining a separation between question and answer material here if possible. (And you can award yourself the green tick too).